# html emails using mail.php

Tags: html, email

Hi i am creating a email system which works on our devbox but on our 1&1 server i get a internal server error 500. The way which i generate the email is by using a simple_dom_parser which reads a html file and replaces  for a specified value. I have managed to get the email to send now and everything works within it. Here is the code

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #eaeaea;'>
            <table width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #fff; width:500px;' >
                <tr>
                    <td><img src='http://www.completelettingsolutions.co.uk/images/email/email_header.jpg' border='0' /></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width='450px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #fff; width:500px;' >
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='padding:0 16px;'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align="left">
                    <font>
                    <span id='fName' style='text-decoration: none;'></span> 
                        <br><br>
                        We've recieved a request for your password to be reset on Complete Letting Solutions. If you've not requested this then rest assured your details are safe and ignore this email!
                        <br><br>
                        Your Username: <span id='uName' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>
                        <br><br>
                        Your Password:  <span id='returnLink' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>               
                        <br><br>
                        Please note - the password reset link above will expire in 24 hours.
                        <br><br>
                        <font color="#4E69B2" size="2" >
                        <b>
                        Kind Regards,<br>
                        Complete Letting Solutions
                        </b>
                    </font>
                    </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:500px;'>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src='http://www.completelettingsolutions.co.uk/images/email/email_foot.jpg' border='0' /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

now all i need to do is align the tables to be centered. Origionaly i was putting them in another table and alignin the td but that gives me a server error. has any one ever experienced this before and does any one know how to fix it? the php versions on both are 5.3.2.

below is the code that dies

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #eaeaea;'>
           <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #eaeaea; width:100%;' >
    <tr>
        <td align='center'>
            <table width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #fff; width:500px;' >
                <tr>
                    <td><img src='http://www.completelettingsolutions.co.uk/images/email/email_header.jpg' border='0' /></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width='450px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #fff; width:500px;' >
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='padding:0 16px;'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align="left">
                    <font>
                    <span id='fName' style='text-decoration: none;'></span> 
                        <br><br>
                        We've recieved a request for your password to be reset on Complete Letting Solutions. If you've not requested this then rest assured your details are safe and ignore this email!
                        <br><br>
                        Your Username: <span id='uName' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>
                        <br><br>
                        Your Password:  <span id='returnLink' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>               
                        <br><br>
                        Please note - the password reset link above will expire in 24 hours.
                        <br><br>
                        <font color="#4E69B2" size="2" >
                        <b>
                        Kind Regards,<br>
                        Complete Letting Solutions
                        </b>
                    </font>
                    </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:500px;'>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src='http://www.completelettingsolutions.co.uk/images/email/email_foot.jpg' border='0' /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
thank you.
```

Comment: HTML won't trigger a 500 status code. The issue is most likely in your PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body style='margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#eaeaea;'>
        <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color:#eaeaea; width:100%;' >
            <tr>
                <td align='center'>
                    <table width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #fff; width:500px;' >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src='http://www.completelettingsolutions.co.uk/images/email/email_header.jpg' border='0' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width='450px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='background-color: #fff; width:500px;' >
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='padding:0 16px;'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align="left">
                                <font>
                                    <span id='fName' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>
                                    <br><br>
                                    We've recieved a request for your password to be reset on Complete Letting Solutions. If you've not requested this then rest assured your details are safe and ignore this email!
                                    <br><br>
                                    Your Username: <span id='uName' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>
                                    <br><br>
                                    Your Password:  <span id='returnLink' style='text-decoration: none;'></span>
                                    <br><br>
                                    Please note - the password reset link above will expire in 24 hours.
                                    <br><br>
                                    <font color="#4E69B2" size="2" >
                                        <b>
                                            Kind Regards,<br>
                                            Complete Letting Solutions
                                        </b>
                                    </font>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table width='500px' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:500px;'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src='http://www.completelettingsolutions.co.uk/images/email/email_foot.jpg' border='0' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

You didn't set the DOC-TYPE, thus the browser couldn't know how to read your code...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it didnt make any change. Seems like a lost cause.. its really wierd.

Comment: Let me grab your code and post a working example... :) Give me a minute

Comment: I've edited my answer and posted an working example of your code :) [ tested @ FF, IE, Google Crome, Safari and Opera]

Comment: Error 500 - Internal server error

An internal server error has occured!
Please try again later.

there must be something wrong server side. the code runs fine as you said when it isnt sent though mail.php on the server. Dam 1&1 lol. we getting our own dedicated server which will be the same as the devbox so hopefully that will get rid of the problem. Thank you

Comment: Yep.. if you'll have the production code on the same server as the devbox that's providing all the results ok, you're in the clear :)
Ps: if you're done with this topic, mark the question as the right answer and vote, to close the subject! :)